# How Do I stop Ubuntu (22.04 LTS) From Resuming Automatically From HIbernation

Tags: hibernate, resume

I configured ubuntu to hibernate using the guide in the [link](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/08/how-to-enable-hibernation-on-ubuntu.html)
Everything Appears to work fine except for the fact that my system keeps resuming from hibernation immediately after a successful hibernation.
The only line that changed n my grub config:
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=2f8581dc-9788-414c-8525-5f844eed53df resume_offset=4603904"`

System Info

[system info linked here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYXF6.png)

Comment: Is the MacBook using WiFi or Ethernet? If it’s the latter, Wake-on-LAN may be interfering 

Comment: Check /proc/wakeup ; switch all to disable witch echo NAME > /proc/wakeup

Answer (score 1):

@Adam is right. It was the laptop lid (`LID0`) in my case that was making the system resume instantly. I disabled it using the command `echo "LID0" > /proc/acpi/wakeup`. Thanks!

Comment: Is this a MacBook?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file `/etc/systemd/sleep.conf` with the following configuration:

```
[Sleep]
HibernateMode=shutdown
```

Then, use `sudo systemctl hibernate` to trigger hibernation.

As explained in the manual of [systemd-sleep](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-systemd-sleep/), the variable `HibernateMode` is written to `/sys/power/disk` right before hibernating.
Without setting it to `shutdown`, systemd will use the default `"platform"`, which may not work in some systems.
With `shutdown` it should force the machine to power off after saving to disk. Other options are `reboot` and `platform`, explained here: [kernel.org](https://kernel.org/doc/html/latest/power/basic-pm-debugging.html). I had exactly the same problem in OpenSUSE after an OS update and this configuration solved it for me.